# Calculate percentage by group in one column using dplyr, ignoring blanks

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to calculate the percentage in the column 'Color', ignoring blanks.

Example:

**Df**

```
Color
green

green
blue
blue
blue

blue
```

**Code**

```
  Df %>%
    group_by(color) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    mutate(per = n/sum(n, na.rm = TRUE))
```

**Desired output:**

```
Color  n   per
green  2   0.33
blue   4   0.67
```

What is the code missing? I know this is a simple question, and would really appreciate insights you could offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code, and it seems to work except that the output includes a row for `NA` values, which I assume is the issue you're having.  I would fix it like this:

```
df %>% filter(!is.na(color)) %>%
   count(color) %>%
   mutate(per = n/sum(n))
```

or, if you need something that runs even faster on large data sets:

```
df <- df[!is.na(df$color),] %>% count(color)
df$per <- df$n/sum(df$n)
```

Comment: You're the best! Tried the filter and it worked, good to know an alternate solution too :)